# nfc-pcsc with NFC-Reader ACR122U: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WriteError: Write operation failed: Status code: 0x6300

Tags: javascript, node.js, nfc

I'm using nfc-pcsc library with an ACR122U connected to a Systec CTR-500 PLC running Node-RED (=node.js).
My NFC card is integrated into the Nordic µC nRF52840 and it seems to be the same as NXP NTAG213/215/216 which is not a Mifare.
It's formatted to NFC Type 2.
Reading and writing in principle works. The node-red-contrib-nfc-pcsc includes your nfc-pscs:

```
const { NFC } = require("nfc-pcsc");
```

I don't know what happened but since a few days after calling

```
await reader.write(4,outData);
```

I get the error:

```
(node:268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WriteError: Write operation failed: Status code: 0x6300
at ACR122Reader.write (/root/.node-red/node_modules/nfc-pcsc/dist/Reader.js:493:13)
(node:268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 5)
```

Reader.js:493:13 is only printing the error:

```
if (statusCode !== 0x6300) {
      throw new _errors.WriteError(_errors.OPERATION_FAILED, `Write operation failed: Status code: 0x${statusCode.toString(16)}`);
}
```

However the data is written correctly, I can't recognize any error. But I'd like to understand the error message. What could lead to error 0x6300?

The capability container CC3 of the Type 2 header is set to 0x00 which means read and write access granted without any security.

Furthermore I tried to implement try-catch around `await reader.write(4,outData);` and aborted write process so that not all data are written successfully. But everytime I get this 0x6300 error independent if successful or aborted writing.

I'd be happy if some could give me a hint for this error.
If any information is missing don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks a lot!

I expect no error when all is working fine. Otherwise I expect some documentation about the error to understand what's happening.

Comment: Does someone have an idea? How can I get more information about this error 0x6300? And is it generally possible to catch an aborted write process with pcsc-library?
Would be very happy if someone could help me in this issue.